# When is a good time to slack off?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-3

The farmer class has a skill that lets me slack off for 1 hour at the cost of 2 sp.  What is the purpose of this skill and when should I use it?

Comment: When the boss isn't looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Horseplay, as you've noted, simply advances the game clock by one hour. While it seems useless on the surface (and, according to some, it mostly is, for reasons explained below), it's not entirely without use.

For example, if you're gathering in the dungeon late at night, advancing the clock to midnight will reset your harvesting allowances. Most players seem to usually recommend Double Crop for harvesting runs instead, but one small benefit that Horseplay offers over Double Crop is that it only takes a single skill point to invest in, and has no significant TP cost, which can be useful in the early game.

Another minor use is as a way to manipulate the in-game clock for specific dungeon events that only occur at specific times of day.

Comment: Personally? Your "minor use" at the end is what I've always figured the major use to be. Slack Off is the means to manipulate time without the risks of running into encounters, and also at a much faster rate than one hour per 30 turns. Changing time of day to alter encounter contents or FOE behavior, basically. And, well, to generate silly messages about how exactly your Farmer managed to waste everyone's time for a whole hour.